# How to programmatically change elements from another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog with a custom layout as content.

```
filterMainDialog.setContentView(R.layout.filter_main);
```

Everything works fine(display and stuff) but if I try to programmatically change elements from that layout (like checking a radio button)  my app crashes and I tried every method possible. Any advice?

Comment: can you mention logcats and with custom dialog?

Comment: can you please add your code and the stack trace of the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's probably because your layout is not yet inflated your onCreate should look a bit like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View content = View.inflate(getActivity(),
            R.layout.add_quantity_produced_dialog_frag, null);

    mNewQuantity = content.findViewById(R.id.new_quantity);
    mNewQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(mOriginalQuantity));

    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(content)
            .create();

    return dialog;
}
```